# how to use integer value in QString

Tags: c++, qt

I have a program in which I want to use QString in a Qlabel :

```
      text1->setText(QString("Actual value of Threshold: %1 mV").arg(slider->value()*2.745098));
```

well this work fine, but I would like to get integer value like **100 mV** instead of **100.84654mV** any Idea how can I do.

```
silder->value();
```

is given an integer value back. and casting like :

```
 text1->setText(QString("Actual value of Threshold: %1 mV").arg((int)slider->value()*2.745098));
```

Comment: Can you cast to an `int`?

Comment: I tried, but I get an  error

Comment: What error did you get? Does the argument have to be of type `double`? If so, then you can call `round()` from `math.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast the calculated value to int.

```
text1->setText(QString("Actual value of Threshold: %1 mV").arg((int)(slider->value()*2.745098)));
```

Comment: to cast like this, doesn't change anything, I already tried it. It must be one of Qt functions.

Comment: Did you try QString::number(slider->value()*2.745098,g,0);

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = qRound(slider->value() * 2.745098);
QString text = QString("Actual value of Threshold: %1 mV").arg(value);
```